# creating a trigger in php-my-admin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i would like to create a trigger using the phpmyadmin "add trigger" option. 
The Trigger should run AFTER every INSERT in table comments that takes the highest "number of comments" (nc in DB) from the table "POST" and takes the "ID" and the "question" of that row and puts it in the "top_questions" table

Update1:
i want the top 5 records with the 5 highest "number of comments" sorted descendingly to be put into the table Top Questions

Post Table:
[post table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukmuE.png)

Top Questions Table:[top_questions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Gi9.png)

MCO stands for "most commented on" and that's where the question needs to be taken from post and put in

Comment Table:
[comment table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duUjL.png)

update2: at this point i'm wondering should i make it as a trigger, view, or  materialized view? (i would still prefer it as a trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put it by selecting after insert command

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO top_question(MCO,PID)
SELECT ID,P_ID FROM `comment_tbl` GROUP BY P_ID order by COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10    

END
```

just put this lines in phpmyadmin in trigger (select after insret in commaent table )

Comment: i would prefer if you write it for me thank you , oh and 1 more thing i'm using the "add trigger" function in phpmyadmin should that change your answer, and what do t1 and t2 represent? table1 and table2?and in which case which would be t1 and which would be t2 and also "after" "insert" on which table though is my question "post" or "comments"?

Comment: maybe if wrote wrong your table name correct it by your self

Comment: still giving me an error #1064 and this is what i typed

BEGIN

INSERT INTO top_question(top_questions.MCO,top_questions.P_ID)
SELECT count(*),top_questions.P_ID , top_questions.MCO FROM comments GROUP BY top_questions.P_ID order by COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5    

END

And i also want them to be grouped by the "nc" that is in the "post" table, ordered descendingly THEN inserted into the "top question" table

Comment: you forget to put * in count , count(*)  , ERROR 1064 .  and then let me know your nc in post was update every time you insret a comment or you want do it with my trigger ? maybe I will go sleep till you answer this question but next morning I will help you .

Comment: BEGIN
INSERT INTO top_questions(top_questions.MCO,top_questions.P_ID)
SELECT count(*),top_questions.P_ID,top_questions.MCO FROM comments GROUP BY top_questions.P_ID order by COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 5    
END

Its there and its not working, let me run the problem by you again because i think there is a misunderstanding, i need to take top 5 posts according to their "nc" in the table "post"  then order them descendingly and have them entered in the "Top questions" table with their "ID" &"question" from the table "Post"

Comment: And i would appreciate if u stay up, this is due tomorrow, if its not too much trouble.

Comment: nc will increase via PHP code, im only handling the DB side

Comment: so this didnt solve it, but you really helped and thanks for that.

Comment: hey sir , now I exactly know what you want , I'll update my answer . check it out in next 30 mins

Comment: and the final question is  what different between   MCO, P_ID I think so MCO is the most commented post_id ,